# Fermat's principle and a non-physical conclusion

Tags: optics, refraction, geometric-optics, variational-principle

Fermat's Principle is the statement that a ray will follow a minimum-time path between a point, A, to a point, B.

So, if I have a block of material of high refractive index, so that it slows the light considerably inside, the least-time path should avoid going through this block. In the picture below, in the topmost part a light ray going straight through the block is shown, in the bottommost the light ray goes around the object. Obviously, this situation does not occur and in reality, the ray goes straight through the block. Why does this not contradict Fermat's principle?

[image]

Comment: I would add that Fermat's principle is not even true for dispersive materials because there is no "time of flight" for those to begin with. The system will show a different response time for different frequencies and now the uncertainty relation is rearing its ugly head.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Well, [Fermat's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_principle) is really a principle of [stationary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stationary_point) time rather than [least](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_and_minimum) time. There is a stationary path through the block of high refractive index.

See [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/567920/2451) Phys.SE post for a related example.

Comment: So, the minimum-time formulation is just wrong? Just asking again, because it is stated often that way...

Comment: $\uparrow$ Yes.

Comment: I can't believe that, I have been lied to my whole life :D

Comment: The distinction between *local* extrema (local maxima and minima) and *global* extremal points is quite important in many areas in mathematics and physics, and it is a good idea to pay a careful attention to this distinction...

Comment: @StefanH probably not a bad thing. It's common in education, called [lie-to-children](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie-to-children)

Comment: And in a very real sense, all of high school physics is a "lie-to-children" (see: Quantum Mechanics, and General Relativity).

Answer (score 9):

To add to @Qmechanic's answer: The "shortest flight" formulation of Fermat's principle is true only "locally" for a sufficiently narrow angle bundle of rays. Take an elliptical reflector that can ideally image light from one of its focus to another. The direct straight line connection between them is the shortest path from one to another. The "shortest flight principle" here is applicable locally for those rays that are *constrained* to hit the elliptical wall before going reaching the other focal point.